# linux scipt writing to generate executable

Tags: linux

I am new to linux , I have to write a script in linux to automate the generation of executable file resulting from linking and compiling lex and yacc files, my script and lex and yacc files should be in the same director

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at make and Make files, as they excel at this very purpose. See this tutorial http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/